# Send base64 string to server as String Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a cropping module for my AngularJS web page to create avatar, which generates avatar as a base64 string like:

```
DataURI=
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEYAAABGCAYAAABxLuKEAAAAu0lEQVR4Xu3UsQ0AMAzDsOb/p/tAMminTxAIz7O1wOiyFxDmkCGMMO00iCGGmFaAmNbLxxBDTCtATOvlY4ghphUgpvXyMcQQ0woQ03r5GGKIaQWIab18DD
    ....
    tF4+hhhiWgFiWi8fQwwxrQAxrZePIYaYVoCY1svHEENMK0BM6+VjiCGmFSCm9fIxxBDTChDTevkYYohpBYhpvXwMMcS0AsS0Xj6GGGJaAWJaLx9DDDGtADGtl485en31GQBH1BvQzgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
```

the problem s that I could not put this string into the URL and send it to server - I got an error while trying to do that:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8180/ChatRestNoSQLMaven/rest/AccountService/updateAvatar/7900b92e-fcfd-4eb4-a39c-c908214c1e7a/data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBD
>
> ...
>   igAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/Z.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.103:8182' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

and

> angular.min.js:93 GET
>   http://localhost:8180/ChatRestNoSQLMaven/rest/AccountService/updateAvatar/7…oAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/Z
>   400 ()

What is the best way to encode it for Javascript?

I found some examples for php which are not working, but could not fins something in JS.

PHP example 1:

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
 return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

PHP example 2:

```
$str = 'Some String';

$encoded = urlencode( base64_encode( $str ) );
$decoded = base64_decode( urldecode( $encoded ) );
```

My URL:

```
const urlUploadAvatar = "http://" + host + "/ChatRestNoSQLMaven/rest/AccountService/updateAvatar/"+securityKey+"/"+DataURI;
```

Thank you!

Comment: try to post this value using form data instead of url.

Comment: Why do you want to send it on the URL? *Even worse*, why would you want to send something called `securityKey` on the URL?

Comment: securityKey is my session id, based on which i'll be able to get userid, etc. I just need to put the image to my Cassandra db thru back end (java)

Comment: `I got an error while trying to do that.` um, whats the error?

Comment: use POST/PUT instead of GET

Comment: @chiliNUT updated

Comment: @Sreekumar same result for 'get'

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` is probably the key here. You are making a cross-domain post, but you aren't configured to allow it.

Comment: @MattBurland I have no problems with all other request from this page to exact same server

Comment: You're asking the server for the image when you send it as part of the URL - oops! You need to _send_ it there, so pack the image up as you have then send it as data, as so many others have said.